# How to call one javascript asset only in laravel?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, assets, laravel-3

In my base controller, I added two asset inside:

```
    Asset::script('jquery', 'js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js');

    Asset::script('test', 'js/test.js');
```

But when I called : `Asset::script`, all these two .js files are loaded. But I would like to call `jquery`, not `test`, how can I do so? Thanks.

Comment: Is this because you don't want to load test.js in a specifc view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use two containers. `Asset::script('name','path')` will add the script to the default container. And it will output the whole container for you later when you call `Asset:scripts()` in the template file.

You can add a different container for either test.js or jquery, like this:

```
Asset::container('myContainerName')->add('test', 'js/test.js');
```

Then later in your template file you can output only the scripts from the container named "myContainerName" like this:

```
echo Asset::container('myContainerName')->scripts();
```

This isn't exactly the same as outputting a specific script from a single container, but it will give you your desired result.

Read more about containers in the official documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/views/assets